# Regex - test or match

Tags: javascript, regex

This might be being picky, but I wondered what the most efficient workflow is when using regex; should I use `test` with `exec`, or `exec` only?

Example: I have a regex which I use to remove all non-word (`\W`) after the last character (`\w`).

E.g.

```
var str = 'Example string with _some weird formatting at the end *_&^',
    reg = /(.*\w)/;
```

What's more efficient:

```
if (reg.test(str)) {
    str = reg.exec(str)[0];
}
```

vs.

```
var res = reg.exec(str);
str = (res && res[0]) || str;
```

Also, is there a way either can cause an exception to be thrown?

Comment: The most efficient is to not use `test` or `exec` but to use `replace` directly.

Answer (score 2):

***Bottom line:*** regular expressions are expensive compared to most methods.

`reg.test()` and `reg.exec()` will each run the expression against the target `str`, so it will be more expensive than just running `reg.exec()`.

---

However, if you're trying to replace data, you can use [`str.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace):

```
str = str.replace(/\W+$/, '');
```

Not only is this fast (just one expression is evaluated), but it's also pragmatic. There's not much better than pragmatic solutions!

---

*<sub>**Note:** When in doubt, [test](https://jsperf.com/)!</sub>*

Comment: Is there any time I'd use `RegExp.exec` as opposed to `String.replace`? `RegExp.exec` does some funny "stuff" when using the `global` flag (which I haven't completely worked out what).

Comment: @keldar...if you want to replace text, use `String.replace()`. If you want to search a string, use `RegExp.exec()`. If you just need a `true`/`false` return, use `RegExp.test()` or `String.search()`. *(paraphrased from [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec))*

Answer (score 1):

You can use a very useful site named jsperf.com to compare your different test case performance.

You can check a benchmark comparison between your both codes here:

**[test with exec VS exec-only](http://jsperf.com/test-with-exec-or-exec-only)**

This is the result:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Likewise - not sure why though, can't see anything obvious.

Comment: @keldar your question is quite valid, however you may have an idea about what is ovious or not but you can see a benchmark result with a report, measures and number to understand exactly what is the idea you have. Hope the benchmark is insightful for your

Comment: Sorry - somebody deleted their comment saying "the code generates an error on jsPerf", and I was replying to that saying "Likewise - ", I received the error, "can't see anything obvious", no obvious error in the set up. Your jsPerf is extremely helpful!